# HTML5/ Javascript not drawing tiles on the far right side of screen

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently having issues  drawing tiles at the far right of screen and  cant figure out what could be causing this. as you can see in the image linked below the floor tiles are supposed to be going to the right edge of the screen.

[image: Image Of what is happening]

here is a copy of the code for the array that its drawing from

```
var mapArray1 = new Array();
//               05|                 10|                15|                  20|        
mapArray1[0] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00);
mapArray1[1] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00);               
mapArray1[2] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00);
mapArray1[3] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00);               
mapArray1[4] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 61, 00, 00, 00, 00, 33, 00, 00, 43);               
//
mapArray1[5] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 01, 01, 21, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01);               
mapArray1[6] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 21, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00);               
mapArray1[7] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 63, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 21, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00);               
mapArray1[8] = new Array(01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 21, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00);               
mapArray1[9] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 21, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 02);               
//10
mapArray1[10] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 21, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 02);              
mapArray1[11] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 00, 01, 21, 01, 01, 01, 01, 02);              
mapArray1[12] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 21, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00);              
mapArray1[13] = new Array(00, 00, 00, 00, 50, 00, 02, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 21, 00, 41, 00, 00, 00);              
mapArray1[14] = new Array(01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01);
```

and here is the code that is drawing it

```
function CreateBlock(tileInt, column, row, bm){
    var tileWidth = gameConstants.TILEWIDTH;

    var blockModel = new AVerletModel();
    blockModel._xPos = column * tileWidth + tileWidth/2;
    blockModel._yPos = row * tileWidth + tileWidth/2;
    blockModel.SetRectangle(tileWidth, tileWidth, 0xFF7777);
    vBlocks.push(blockModel);

    var blockView = new AVerletView(context);
    blockView.Init(blockModel, bm, tileInt);
    vViews.push(blockView);
}

function CreateLvl(mbm, obm, ebm){
    //console.log("CreateLVL");
    //now we must create the level
    for(var i = 0;i< gameConstants.TILESACROSS; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < gameConstants.TILESDOWN; j++){
            //defining a target
            var newPlacement;
            var iTileInt = mMap.getTile(currentMap, j, i);
            var iTileType = Math.round(iTileInt / 10);
            var iMod = iTileInt % 10;

            if(iTileInt != 0){
                if(iTileInt < 10){
                    CreateBlock(iTileInt, i, j, mbm);
                }
                else if(iTileType == gameConstants.ENEMY){
                    console.log("enemy");
                    //CreateEnemy(iMod, i, j, ebm);
                }
                else{ 
                    switch(iTileType){
                        case gameConstants.ORB:
                            newPlacement = new SpriteView(context);
                            newPlacement.Init(iMod, obm, iTileType);
                            vOrbs.push(newPlacement);
                            newPlacement._xPos = i * gameConstants.TILEWIDTH;
                            newPlacement._yPos = j * gameConstants.TILEWIDTH;
                        break;
                        case gameConstants.LADDER:
                            newPlacement = new SpriteView(context);
                            newPlacement.Init(iMod, obm, iTileType);
                            vViews.push(newPlacement);
                            newPlacement._xPos = i * gameConstants.TILEWIDTH;
                            newPlacement._yPos = j * gameConstants.TILEWIDTH;
                        break;
                        case gameConstants.GOAL:
                            goal = new SpriteView(context);
                            goal.Init(iMod, mbm, iTileType);
                            goal._xPos = i * gameConstants.TILEWIDTH;
                            goal._yPos = j * gameConstants.TILEWIDTH;
                        break;
                        case gameConstants.RAINBOW:
                            newPlacement = new SpriteView(context);
                            //console.log(newPlacement.currentTile);
                            newPlacement.Init(5, obm, iTileType);
                            vViews.push(newPlacement);
                            newPlacement._xPos = i * gameConstants.TILEWIDTH;
                            newPlacement._yPos = j * gameConstants.TILEWIDTH;
                        break;
                        case gameConstants.GEMS:
                            newPlacement = new SpriteView(context);
                            newPlacement.Init(iMod, obm, iTileType);
                            vGems.push(newPlacement);
                            newPlacement._xPos = i * gameConstants.TILEWIDTH;
                            newPlacement._yPos = j * gameConstants.TILEWIDTH;
                        break;
                    }
                }//else

            }//if

        }//for
    }//for
};
```

Comment: The image doesn't appear to be there. And what is the code that works with this array?

Comment: How does this array show us what's going wrong with your HTML?

Comment: i have added the code and fixed the picture issue now  any help would be apreaciated thanks

Comment: Is the loop is terminating before it has traversed the entire array? Is the problem in your loop logic or your tile-drawing procedure?

Comment: The CreateBlock function is being called 59 times, but it's only drawing 49 tiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be in your draw function.  You are pushing to the vViews vector whenever you make a block, a rainbow, or a ladder.  Be sure you are calling draw on 59 blocks plus however many of the others you have.  Can you post the function?

Comment: you are correct i was only calling it on the blocks  thanks so much :)